# jQuery removeClass failed to remove when JSON is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this HTML structure :

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 p-l-0">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select class="kurir">
        <option select="selected"></option>
        ...
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group form-group-default form-group-default-select2 required">
        <select id="tarif" class="tarif full-width">
        ...
        </select>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-12 notarif">
        <p class="small hint-text no-margin text-danger hidden">
            some text here.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

and I have this javascript :

```
$(".kurir").change(function() {
    var _thiscache = $(this);
    $.ajax({
        url: json_url,
        dataType: "JSON",
        success: function(json){

            if ( json.length == 0 ) {
                $(".tarif").prop("disabled", true);
                $(".tarif").select2("val", "");
                _thiscache.closest(".row").find(".notarif").$("p").removeClass("hidden");
            }

        }
    ...
```

why I can't remove `hidden` class on `p` when JSON gives me empty result? what did I missed here? thank you for your attention.

Comment: then do `else{_thiscache.closest(".row").find(".notarif").$("p").removeClass("hidden");}`

Comment: `_thiscache.closest(".row").find(".notarif p.hidden").removeClass("hidden");`

Comment: do you think the syntax `find(".notarif").$("p")` is valid? I don't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of

```
_thiscache.closest(".row").find(".notarif").$("p").removeClass("hidden"); //wrong selector and syntax
```

Use

```
_thiscache.closest(".row").find(".notarif p.hidden").removeClass("hidden");
```